# IE10 does not process jquery file upload request

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-10, jquery-file-upload

I have a strange problem on my Win 8 / ie10 machine. I'm posting my files with the jquery fileupload plugin to an MVC 4 controller method.

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: baseUrl + "/Profile/UploadImage",
        done: function (e, data) {
            var r = data.result;
            if (r.success) {
                if (jcrop_api)
                    jcrop_api.destroy();
                setCrop();

                jcrop_api.setImage(r.fileUri);
                $('#previewImage').attr('src', '');
                $("#cropForm").dialog("open");
            }
        }
    });
```

This works great in chrome but when I tried it in IE10 today it started the request but never returned. The MVC Controller method is never hit. There are no errors in the F12 console of IE10. The network tab in the IE console lists the request as pending. Are there any known problems at the moment?

Comment: crazy, it works in IE9 mode...

Comment: I am facing almost similar issue. If you have solved the problem, can you answer your own question?

Comment: I'm sad to say I have not resolved this. When switching to IE9 mode (via debug console) it works and this is super crazy.

Comment: Thanks for update. I will need to use something else it seems. Will update here if I could resolve it.

Comment: I ran into cross browser support hell when I was writing an upload script.  In the end I used [Fineuploader](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader) to handle all the required browsers. Not an answer to a question but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem to. In my case, I was using the response content-type "application/json" which doesn't seem to be supported by IE.

Changing it to "text/plain" did the trick for me.